# Perimeter of mocha, waffle and chai

Tags: solidity, testing, mocha

Here is what i've understood (please tell me if i am wrong):

- Mocha (mochajs.org) is a testing framework
- Waffle (getwaffle.io) is another testing framework
- chai: This is not a framework, this is a library which contains helpers for assertions
- openzeppelin-test-helpers: This is not a framework: This is just helpers. And some of this helpers are calling chai helpers

Mocha and Waffle syntaxes are very similar and looks like something like that:

```
describe(... it('...) =>  ...)
```

There is something i do not understand: Look at this project:

```
https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/master/package.json
```

I can see both mocha and waffle dependencies.

How is it possible to work with 2 testing frameworks ?

Thanks

Comment: Waffle uses mocha underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Waffle and Mocha are both test frameworks, they are used for different things.

- Mocha runs your tests, as defined with `describe`, `it`, etc.
- Chai asserts that the values in your tests are correct. (`expect`, `assert`)
- Waffle provides tools for compiling and deploying contracts, functions for testing contracts, contract mocks, extra Chai assertions etc. It can be used in addition to Mocha (as well as other test runners like Jest), Waffle does not run tests itself.

Comment: so when i see "describe... it...", this is mocha ?

Comment: Mocha is one of the frameworks that works with `describe`, `it`, etc., yes. Other test frameworks like Jest, Jasmine use a similar pattern.

Comment: I mean if i see « describe... it... » in a project, it must be mocha ?

Comment: Not by definition, cause, like I mentioned, Jest, Jasmine and possibly other test runners use `describe`, `it`, etc. as well.

Comment: okay so this is not a "similar" pattern, this is the "same" pattern ?

Comment: The exact implementation is likely different. Each framework has different features to offer, otherwise there would be no point in having multiple frameworks in the first place. If you're just talking about the use of the function names `describe` and `it`, then yes, it's the same.